# How to make one to one relationship EER diagram in MySql Workbench 6.3E

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, diagram

As the title said , how can i make the relationship in following image (connect to column)?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the vertical toolbar you can see different connection (relation) tools. The last one with the picker symbol lets you select individual columns for a relationship. You can edit the cardinality and other properties at any time in the relationship editor (double click the relationship to open it). By editing the referencing table you can also edit the participating columns (via the created foreign key constraint.

Comment: that works great except it only ever gives a 1:n relationship. I can't see any way in the editor to change that to 1:1 The editor shows only Caption, @nd Capt.,Comments, and Visibility Settings. The only other 1:1 tool does not allow use of existing columns, it auto selects so there appears to be no way to choose columns for a 1:1 relationship. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Double click the relationship and the editor for it will open. There you can change the cardinality.

Comment: I don't see that. Maybe my version (6.3.9) doesn't support that feature. All I see after double-clicking the relationship  is 3 fields (Caption, @nd Capt, Comments) and a Visibility Settings radio selection (Fully Visible, Draw Split, Hide)

Comment: OK it seems that 6.3E is the enterprise version and I'm using the GA version which doesn't support that feature, I guess.

Comment: I just installed 6.3.10 CE and same result. However https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/features.html seems to indicate ER Diagramming Complete entity-relationship diagramming for the community edition but for me it ain't so.

Comment: There are 2 tabs in the relationship editor (Relationship and Foreign Key), at the bottom. Switch to the second for the other details.

Comment: Totally missed that. See it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you don't have primary key in your table it won't work as expected.